# How to select rows until an element is encountered in a column?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's suppose we have the following dataframe :

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], data = [1,2,3,3])
```

which gives us the following dataframe :

```
df
   0
A  1
B  2
C  3
D  3
```

I was looking for a quick way (during a certain time) to extract the rows until the first occurrence of `3` for instance is encountered.

I found a solution (written in the answer section below) but I wonder if there are other more conventional approaches.

Thanks in advance for your contributions.

**Solution found**

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], data = [1,2,3,3])

mask = df[0].eq(3).cumsum().cumsum().le(1)
r = df[mask]

print(r)
```

```py
   0
A  1
B  2
C  3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a boolean mask with [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html):

```
# find values for which the previous row is 3
m = df[0].shift().eq(3)

# keep only before the first one
out = df[~m.cummax()]
```

As a one-liner:

```
out = df[~df[0].shift().eq(3).cummax()]
```

Output:

```
   0
A  1
B  2
C  3
```

Alternative:

```
m = df[0].shift().ne(3)

out = df[m.cummin()]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) directly to find the first index where the number "3" is found:

```
# Getting list of index where 3 appears
index_with_num = df.loc[df[0] == 3].index.tolist()

# If 3 appeared, we filter the dataframe
if index_with_num:
    df_new = df.loc[:index_with_num[0], :].copy()
```

Or, you could loop through the dataframe and stop the loop after you find the first 3 occurrence:

```
# Looping through the dataframe
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row[0] == 3:
        break

# assigning the filtered dataframe to a new copy
df_new = df.loc[:index, :].copy()
```